# Pandas split a columns value and assign back to the column

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with following pandas data frame that has a column containing date as a string. Date also has time.

```
(Pdb) temp_df_no_na['logged_dt'].head(n=5)
0    01/19/2010 00:00:00.000000
1    03/28/2009 00:00:00.000000
2    09/22/2005 00:00:00.000000
3    12/14/2010 00:00:00.000000
5    02/23/2010 00:00:00.000000
```

I want to split by the space between date at the time and keep only the date part.

I wrote following lambda function and did an apply. It did work but end up getting warning and I am worried that results might be corrupt. Why would I get a warning like this:

```
temp_df_no_na['logged_dt'] =  temp_df_no_na['logged_dt'].apply(lambda x:x.split(" ")[0] if(x.split(" ") > 0) else x)
```

Here is the warning

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  from dataFrameCreator import DataFrameCreator

(Pdb) temp_df_no_na['logged_dt'].head(n=5)
0    01/19/2010
1    03/28/2009
2    09/22/2005
3    12/14/2010
5    02/23/2010
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***method 1***
get `Timestamp` with pd.to_datetime

```
temp_df_no_na.logged_dt = pd.to_datetime(temp_df_no_na.logged_dt)
temp_df_no_na.logged_dt

0   2010-01-19
1   2009-03-28
2   2005-09-22
3   2010-12-14
5   2010-02-23
Name: logged_dt, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

***method 2***
`dt.strftime`

```
temp_df_no_na.logged_dt = pd.to_datetime(temp_df_no_na.logged_dt).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
temp_df_no_na.logged_dt

0   2010-01-19
1   2009-03-28
2   2005-09-22
3   2010-12-14
5   2010-02-23
Name: logged_dt, dtype: object
```

---

***mehtod 3***
`str.split`

```
temp_df_no_na.logged_dt = temp_df_no_na.logged_dt.str.split().str[0]
temp_df_no_na.logged_dt

0   2010-01-19
1   2009-03-28
2   2005-09-22
3   2010-12-14
5   2010-02-23
Name: logged_dt, dtype: object
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the lambda function i mentioned do you see an issue with that function

Comment: the lambda looks fine.  method 3 is a vectorized version of that.  Your SettingWithCopyWarning is indicative of `temp_df_no_na` being tied to another dataframe.  It's warning you that you are assigning to it when it is a copy of something else.  That isn't related to the question you asked though.